# urlpatterns in django for unicode names

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was working on categories in my website and after adding category with id like 11 or more it had a error .
Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('more-cat', 14)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P[\w-]+)/(?P[0-9])/']

its the urls.py

```
re_path(r'^category/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<id>[0-9])/' , views.listofproducts , name="category"),
```

and its models.py

```
class category(models.Model):
sub_category = models.ForeignKey('self' , on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True , blank=True , related_name='sub')
sub_cat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200 , blank=True , null=True)
create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True ,blank=True , null=True)
update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True ,blank=True , null=True)
slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True , unique=True , null=True , blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'category' , blank=True , null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("home:category" , args=[self.slug , self.id])
```

please help me with this problem.!

Comment: You should add a `+` at the `[0-9]` character group, otherwise it can only use one-digit numbers.

Comment: can you please say where exactly i have to add this?

Comment: replace `[0-9]` with `[0-9]+`.

Comment: thank you ! it worked